# Amazon API Gateway IAM authenticated example with generated JS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have created sample GET and POST APIs on Amazon API Gateway following their official documentation. I have generated JS SDK for these APIs, which I am using to call these APIs from a client-side JS file hosted on S3. This works flawlessly without any 'Authorization Type'.

Now, when I set 'Authorization Type' for GET method as 'IAM', I am required to pass IAM credentials in order for it to work. In spite of passing my AWS account's root credentials, I am getting this in the response headers:

```
x-amzn-ErrorType:InvalidSignatureException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.coral.service/
```

And finally it returns a **403** error code.

My question is: Has anyone successfully attempted to use generated javascript SDK from Amazon API Gateway with IAM authentication? Can you point where I might be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this question would be best posed to Amazon Customer / Technical Support. But if you do get an answer there, please do post the solution here as well :)

Comment: I already asked this question on AWS forum, however still waiting for an answer. Thought of checking out the bigger community here. :) Either ways, I will keep posted if I have it working.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the SDK generation. Also, friendly reminder, never use your root credentials anywhere, create admin `IAM` user instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the help of few folks on AWS Forum. It appears that the API Gateway GET method expects an empty body. By default, if you are following the README sample that comes with generated JS SDK, passing 'undefined' or just '{}' inside the body to GET causes a non-matching payload and this results in an incorrect signature being calculated.

As of now, I just made a small tweak in the /lib/apiGatewayCore/sigV4Client.js by hardcoding the `body = ''`.

This should be a temporary workout as this may affect your other API Gateway methods that require a filled 'body'. In my case, I only had GET methods.