# AWS Appsync Cache miss and 403 Error on New Device

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am developing an app based on AWS Amplify. While testing on a 2nd local device, I noticed that every graphQL query is failing, returning either a cache miss and/or network error. Most likely depending on the which AppSyncResponseFetchers is used. I have tried both network first and network only, but the queries still fail.

If I open up the app on the emulator or, a different device none of the errors appear so it gives me a reason to believe it is not a configuration error. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app but it does not work.

Any ideas as to what the source of this issue is?

```
2019-03-17 17:24:44.718 32349-32559/com.myapp.android E/myapp.AWSDataService: Error during GraphQL Operation: Cache miss for operation com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.AmNewUserQuery@f7cd3d7
com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloException: Cache miss for operation com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.AmNewUserQuery@f7cd3d7
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloCacheInterceptor.resolveFromCache(ApolloCacheInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloCacheInterceptor.access$100(ApolloCacheInterceptor.java:53)
    at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloCacheInterceptor$1.run(ApolloCacheInterceptor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-03-17 17:24:44.720 32349-32600/com.myapp.android D/RetryInterceptor: Encountered non-retriable error. Returning response    
2019-03-17 17:24:44.721 32349-32600/com.myapp.android E/myapp.AWSDataService: Error during GraphQL Operation: HTTP 403 
        com.apollographql.apollo.exception.ApolloHttpException: HTTP 403 
            at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor.parse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:147)
            at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor.access$100(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:54)
            at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloParseInterceptor$1.onResponse(ApolloParseInterceptor.java:83)
            at com.apollographql.apollo.internal.interceptor.ApolloServerInterceptor$1$1.onResponse(ApolloServerInterceptor.java:110)
            at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
            at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Edit:
Appsync version: 2.7+ (also 2.7.0)

Device 1: Samsung Galaxy S9+ Android 28 (Working)

Device 2: HTC 10             Android 26 (Failed)

Emulator 1: Pixel 2 Android 27 (Working)

Emulator 1: Pixel 2 Android 25 (Working)

I have seen this issue before for a specific query on my main device awhile back. Obviously, I don't know exactly what was causing the issue but I was able to solve it was by logging into my AWS account and resaving the resolver. Without making any functional changes to the resolver it began to work again.

Edit 2:

Using the android debugger, the 403 error is caused by an InvalidSignatureException, "Error from cloudfront"

Possibly related: [Amazon API Gateway IAM authenticated example with generated JS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664874/amazon-api-gateway-iam-authenticated-example-with-generated-js-sdk)

Comment: what is the authentication method of the appsync? (iam / cognito / apikey)?

Comment: IAM, specifically using federated identities with Facebook login.

Comment: can you confirm that you're authenticated before firing the graphql query?

Comment: I believe so. My UserStateDetails is set to SIGNED_IN, and getIdentityId returns the user's CognitoIdentityId.

Comment: Hmm can you try using other AWS services in your apps with that cognito token? e.g. listing objects in an S3 bucket (you have to allow the cognito users to have the s3 permissions). just to make sure it's not a permission issue

Comment: I can call S3Client.generatePresignedUrl without an issue.

Comment: can you provide device details? make, model, and the version of the SDK you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and struggled a lot to find the cause of the issue. Then I check and found that my API key was expired so I recreated my API key and the error was resolved.